# Azure CloudFile UploadFromFile "The specified resource name contains invalid characters"

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files, azure-storage-files

I am trying to upload a file, I get an exception "The specified resource name contains invalid characters".

The path I am using is @"C:\Test\Test.txt".  When I change to relative addressing (i.e., @".\Test.txt") and have the file in the exe folder, it will work.

What I need to know is relative addressing the only option to upload a file to Azure File Storage from a .NET client?  Is there a way to reference a file with a full path and upload to File Storage?

***Update:  Based on the comments and answer below, I realized my mistake:  I was supplying the incoming file path to the GetFileReference method, where this should be the name of the new file in Azure, hence it contained the ':' which was invalid.  Comments are right, I should have provided code, may have been diagnosed easier.***

```
public static async Task WriteFileToStorage(string filePath)
{
    CloudFileShare fileShare = GetCloudFileShare();
    CloudFileDirectory fileDirectory = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
    CloudFile cloudFile = fileDirectory.GetFileReference(filePath);
    await cloudFile.UploadFromFileAsync(filePath);
}
```

Comment: maybe upload a code snippet to show exactly the real problem. I don;t think it should not be possible to upload a local file to Azure file storage

Comment: Agree with Shaddad, I did a quick test, it works fine. Please provide the complete code.

Comment: Purely speculating (considering no code has been shared), I think the name of the file in File Storage is also set as `C:\Test\Test.txt` (instead of Text.txt) and that would cause the upload to fail because it contains `:` in the file name which is an invalid character.

Comment: Thanks all, problem solved (see update above) and lesson learned, should have provided code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net client does support the full path when upload to azure file storage.

You'd better provide the complete code you're using including the file name / path in local and azure file storage.

Here is the code I test with, and it works.(and I'm using the package [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), version 9.3.3 ):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("account_name", "account_key"), true);
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference("test");
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            CloudFile myfile = rootDir.GetFileReference("mytest.txt");

            //the full file path on local
            myfile.UploadFromFile(@"C:\Test\Test.txt");
}
```